# Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm() doesn't return complete URL: CRM 2011 (IE11)

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, internet-explorer-11

I have made a custom close opportunity window for closing opportunities. When opportunity is closed my script uses [Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602956(v=crm.5).aspx#BKMK_OpenEntityForm) for opening a new form (custom entity) with some predefined field values.

Our customer updated their web browsers to IE 11 (latest version that is available right now) and it broke the component for some users but not for all of them.

Their CRM 2011 (On-Premises) has UR 18 installed which should support IE 11.

I have made some debugging and the problem indeed seems not to be in IE 11 itself. It works on my virtual machines (Win 8.1 IE 11 / Win 7 IE 11). They sent us a screenshot of the problem and it seems that for those users who can't use this component correctly Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm() doesn't "work" correctly.

For some users (for those that it works) openEntityForm() opens a new window with URL http://baseurl:portnumber/organizationName/main.aspx?etc=restOfTheStuffInHere

However users who are facing a problem openEntityForm() opens a new window with URL http://baseurl:portnumber/?etc=restOfTheStuffInHere

So it doesn't return organization name and main.aspx part and thus some users are having 404 page instead a new entity form.

They started to have this problem after updating their browsers to IE 11 (from IE 10 I think).

Are there any IE related settings that could produce this problem? Any security setting? Or what could possibly be the problem in here?

Comment: Have you tried put that browsers in compatibility mode?

Comment: I haven't actually. I solved my problem by changing Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm() to windows.open() and I parsed the URL "manually" by using getServerURL(). I'm not able to reproduce the problem with my virtual machines so I can't say right now what the problem was.

Comment: sometimes you can have multiple urls to the same CRM Org depending on deployment type (e.g. you can do SSO and IFD and they will have different urls).  Did you verify users who are running into this issue are all hitting it from the same url as users who are not?